# Easiest way to express reversed identity matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory

Consider the "reverse identity matrix", let's denoted it by $\bf I'$, by which I mean the $n\times n$ matrix with zeros everywhere except on the diagonal from bottom left to the top right (i.e. $(\delta'_{ij})$ where $\delta'_{ij} = 1$ if $i+j = n + 1$ and $0$ otherwise). For example with $n=4$,

$$ \mathbf{I'} = \begin{pmatrix} 
       0&0&0&1\\
       0&0&1&0\\
       0&1&0&0\\
       1&0&0&0
   \end{pmatrix}.
$$

> **Question:** Is there an easy way to express $\bf I'$ in terms of commonly used matrices?

We usually try to express everything using $\bf I$, the usual identity matrix, and $\bf J$, the matrix consisting of all ones, and maybe the adjacency matrices of common graphs such as $K_n$. Also it goes without saying that easy operations such as transpose and so on are allowed.

Comment: If you allow adjacency matrices of common graphs then for $n=2k$, $\bf I'$ is an adjacency matrix of a matching $(1,2k), (2,2k-1),\dots, (k,k+1)$.